# Will using multiple storyboard files increase project build time?

Tags: xcode, xcode-storyboard

My current application has only one story board file with ~100 view controllers. It takes ~10 minutes to load and ~1 minute to build. Will breaking the one storyboard file I currently have into ~20 storyboard files provide me with much, much  quicker load and build times? Note: In the future, the application I am working on may reach over ~100 storyboard files with ~10 view controllers per file. Would this be a reasonable long term solution to this problem? I would like to get the build time down to ~15 seconds instead of several minutes.

Comment: What are the basic specs of your computer? 5 minutes to build?

Comment: What does “load” mean here? Load what?

Comment: @nard 2013 MacBook Pro Retina. Sorry should said ~1 to 2 minutes regarding the build time. Load means loading the sorry board file in XCode.

Comment: *late 2013 MacBook Pro Retina and *story board

Answer (score 1):

We applied multiple storyboards approach instead of one storyboard approach and got a better result in time and teamwork.

Try to reuse your layouts by creating nib files.

Also, think about breaking your project to multiple projects/modules if possible. Try to code as modular as possible so you will have:

- Less build time
- Less maintenance cost
- Reusing modules in other projects
- Better teamwork

Answer (score 0):

Making a storyboard smaller and simpler will definitely make it much faster to open it thru Interface Builder in the Xcode editor.

Moreover, make inferences your Main storyboard smaller and simpler will greatly decrease the launch time and initial memory footprint of your actual app.

However, many other factors influence build times. Xcode now lets you profile your build process, so take advantage of that feature. WWDC 2018 includes an extensive [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/408/) on the topic of build times.

Comment: Please watch https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/408/ too.